# Mac Firefox wheel event triggering delay

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, mousewheel, dom-events

I am using wheel event to scroll a div element. Its working fine in IE 11, Chrome, Windows firefox. But in mac firefox, the events are getting delayed in firing. I need to be implement the scrolling function by wheel event only. Here is a prototype of a code

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("wheel", function(event){
    var scrollAmtY = is_ff > 0 && event.deltaMode == 1 ? - PIXEL_PER_LINE * event.deltaY : -(event.deltaY > SCROLL_LIMIT ? SCROLL_LIMIT : event.deltaY < -SCROLL_LIMIT ? -SCROLL_LIMIT : event.deltaY);
    var scrollAmtX = is_ff > 0 && event.deltaMode == 1 ? - PIXEL_PER_LINE * event.deltaY : -(event.deltaX > SCROLL_LIMIT ? SCROLL_LIMIT : event.deltaX < -SCROLL_LIMIT ? -SCROLL_LIMIT : event.deltaX);
    detailVal.scrollTop(detailVal.scrollTop() - scrollAmtY);
    detailVal.scrollLeft(detailVal.scrollLeft() - scrollAmtX);
});
```

And the var `is_ff` is the firefox check variable and in mac deltaMode is "0" only. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is firefox `quantum` version or normal version?

Comment: Yes the firefox is `quantum` version only. Same version in windows is working fine.

Comment: Can you show what you check variable `is_ff`? Is it work correctly?

Comment: Its just Useragent check only `(agt.indexOf("firefox"))`. The events are triggering after few seconds of the scroll action.

Comment: By the way vertical scroll is working perfectly. But the Horizontal scroll is where the issue occurs, and some time back gesture is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, this issue was due to the mac gestures for front/back buttons. The delay is when there is no front/back operation. If there is front/back operation, that operation takes place.